# Send a digitally signed mail modified by Redemption

Tags: email, digital-signature, outlook-redemption

I am working on Outlook add-in which modifies outgoing message and adds custom attachment just before its sending. It is quite easy with Redemption and **it works fine when sending common mail**.

The problem appears **when the message is digitally signed** by a certificate. In that case, file smime.p7s is automatically attached (it can be read as RDOAttachment), another custom attachment is added and message is modified and sent. However, **recipient gets mail without those modifications and without custom attachment**.

What operations are done in Send method? Is there any protection when data are signed? Is there any solution on how to modify data and to send that attachment? You will probably raise an objection that it is nonsense to modify already signed data, but trust me I have good reason to do that.

C# sample code follows:

```
void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;

    if (mailItem != null)
    {
        mailItem.Save();

        if (mailItem.EntryID != "")
        {
            // get RDOMail
            RDOSession rdoSession = new RDOSession();
            rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
            RDOMail rdoMail = rdoSession.GetMessageFromID(mailItem.EntryID);

            // get info about attachments (e.g. smime.p7s)
            foreach (RDOAttachment attachment in rdoMail.Attachments)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(attachment.FileName);
            }

            // modify body
            rdoMail.HTMLBody = "<html><body>test</body></html>";

            // add some custom attachment
            byte[] data = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };
            RDOAttachment att = rdoMail.Attachments.Add(data);
            att.FileName = "attachment.bin";

            // send modified mail
            rdoMail.Save();
            rdoMail.Send();

            // do not send original message
            Cancel = true;
            mailItem.GetInspector.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook represents signed/encrypted messages as regular MailItem objects. All the changes must be made to that object.

Changes to the actual (on the MAPI level) message will be ignored.

Instead of using rdoSession.GetMessageFromID, try to use rdoSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject.